# Selenium can't accept alert by google chrome [java]

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium can't accept alert by google chrome.

```
    driver.get("http://bubble-export.com/lpg2/");
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
```

Firefox and IE works well.Buy google chrome dose not work!!

How can I accept the alert by google chrome!?

```
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.89)

  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64) 
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-27 00:00:10'

   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.8.0_40'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate when it's a different question? It is specific to Chrome... and the chosen answer here is different to the other question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of accepting alert. You can do this as a hack.Which will remove the alert from appearing

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://bubble-export.com/lpg2/");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};");
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```