# Unable to detect Alert using ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently doing some automation testing using `Selenium WebDriver`.  The issue I am facing is that my script is unable to detect alerts.

Scenario:

I open the application, pass my credentials and press Confirm. On Confirm, the application opens with an Alert. Screenshot of  the Alert Shown below: [image: The alerts asks me to open this software so the application can integrate with other application on my desktop]

I am using Java, Selenium WebDriver, ChromeDriver, and testng.

i am using the codes shows below :

```
uk.setLogin("", "");

uk.getLogin();

WebDriverWait  wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert alert = Driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.accept();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31567785/351861

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not a Javascript Alert, it's called ConfirmBox.

ConfirmBox or Prompt Popups need to be handled differently than Alert Box.

Please try as below

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
System.out.println(alert.getText());
alert.dismiss();
```

It's explained [here](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts)

Comment: And what is the big difference in handling alerts and confirm-boxes? You can use `alert.accept();` with alert as well as with confirm-box

Comment: i have tried with your code and it's still the same.

Comment: @Shah123 What exactly you mean the alert is not getting detected. Could you check the return value of alert.getText(). Let's see it can be any help.

Comment: Failure Exception : org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Comment: The return value is empty. my concern is i do not know what's this Popup is. i have dealt with Alert in the past and it worked perfectly. But, in this case it doesn't do anything.