# Selenium Chromedriver Fails to Detect Alert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently making a selenium webdriver script to launch Zoom meetings. I have been able to do so with SafariDriver with the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://zoom.us/j/0000000000")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.alert_is_present())
except TimeoutException:
    print("The pop-up alert did not load. Please check your internet connection and try again.")
else:
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

However, when I attempt porting it to Chrome with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://zoom.us/j/0000000000")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.alert_is_present())
except TimeoutException:
    print("The pop-up alert did not load. Please check your internet connection and try again.")
else:
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

No matter how long it waits, chromedriver never detects the alert pop-up.

Seemingly duplicate topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741591/unable-to-detect-alert-using-chromedriver) have not worked as chromedriver isn't even detecting the alert in the first place.

I've looked through Selenium webdriver docs trying to find a different method that may be useful but have not found one.

I feel this may be a bug in selenium or chromedriver since the code should port to Chrome but it obviously doesn't.

I have tried looking into driver.execute_script() to execute some useful javascript that may accept the alert, but my javascript knowledge is very limited.

If anyone has any solution, I'm all ears! Thanks!

NOTE: With the Chrome version, calling driver.switch_to.alert.accept(), even after waiting until the alert comes up, raises:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
```

Comment: first: what do you see in Chrome window when you run it ? Do you see alert? Did you use DevTools in Chrome to check if it uses `alert()` to display it? Some portals may send different HTML for different web browser - to correctly display some elements.

Comment: if I try your code with Firefox then I don't see any alert - but If I try with Chrome then it shows popup message which is not part on HTML page so you can't access it from Selenium. Different browsers have different functions and some of then are not part of displayed page - so you can't access it in normal way. I see popup like in question [How to close browser pop-ups using Selenium in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880283/how-to-close-browser-pop-ups-using-selenium-in-python)

Comment: @furas Thanks for the response! (even though it's quite disappointing) Also, can you explain exactly what happens when you use it with Firefox (I don't want to download Firefox just to test this haha)? Does it just go to the except block after the set 5 seconds? Lastly, am I just screwed since it has to do with the browser rather than anything Selenium can access? Is there some other way to click it (besides something like pyautogui I hope)?

Comment: Due to existing issues https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385 as of this writing, alert is not working properly. You can workaround using PyAutoGUI module. https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Comment: in Firefox it doesn't display Popup message - so I don't have to switch and close it. After few second It go to download page. I have installed `zoom` applicationa and I don't know if Chrome would display this popup message if I wouldn't have `zoom` application (this popup proposes to open link external `zoom` application). The only idea to close it is `PyAutoGUI` or similar `pynput` - or I would search (in Google) if some Chrome's option can block popup messages.