# Embedding credentials in URL not working with selenium and chrome

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium for automating testing on a UI thats being developed and I've been stuck trying to access the site because of authentication. I saw that you can authenticate embedding the credentials in the URL like "http://admin:admin@blah.com" but I tried that using Selenium driver as driver.get("http://admin:admin@blah.com") but it isn't working and the popup is still appearing. I also tried grabbing that popup using Alert as driver.switchTo().alert() but its saying that there is no alert. I even included a web wait for the alert and in the browser I can clearly see the popup is there but to no avail. I even tried using the Java Robot to write the credentials but didn't work because we are running it on a headless environment and Robot is throwing an exception.

I saw that you can use third party software like AutoIT or Sikuli but I just wanted to know if there is a specific way you can use the selenium driver for this type of authentication?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT 1:

Ok so thanks to the recommendations from [Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229743/taylor) I managed to get it working on a firefox browser by adding code to handle the alert:

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys(user+Keys.TAB+pass+Keys.TAB);
alert.accept();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

With that code I managed to send the username and password for authentication but for chrome it isn't working. I tried researching on a couple of sites but the only answer thats working for everyone is embedding the credentials in the URL and that is not working for me as described above. One link that was similar was [Selenium can't accept alert by google chrome [java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566646/selenium-cant-accept-alert-by-google-chrome-java) but I don't want to ignore the alert since I need to input the credentials there. Any other help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of authentication is the application expecting?

Comment: The app is expecting basic auth username and password

Comment: Http basic for selenium, try: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/how-to-send-basic-authentication-headers-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

So from what I've read, I believe that the problem is in the chrome driver itself since it can't actually recognize that an alert is there but the firefox driver can. By what I've been looking at one driver supports some things and the other driver supports other things for example you can get the browser logs from chrome but not firefox and you can get the alert from firefox but not with chrome.

I found a turn around for this. Embedding the credentials inside the URL didn't work because the credentials themselves weren't for the page I was testing but for a REST API call that the page does that needed the authentication. Once I figured that out I now make two calls with the driver: the first with the credentials embedded in the URL to the REST call the page makes just so the credentials get cached and reused; and the second to the page itself which now loads with no alert.

Hope this helps anyone else!